# Как авторизоваться на чужом сайте через android приложение?

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование

Хочу создать андроид приложения для сайта, сайт не мой. Приложение будет парсить необходимые данные с сайта и предоставлять пользователю, но для этого нужно авторизоваться. Встал вопрос, как это можно провернуть? В андроид разработке я новичок, поэтому если не сложно, поясните по подробнее. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Авторизоваться и потом работать от имени пользователя можно. Как именно - зависит от конкретного сайта и используемых для авторизации и аутентификации методов.

Comment: Что бы понять как происходит авторизация, потребуется немного погрузиться в инструменты нагрузочного тестирования, начиная с jmeter, фидлер и скрупулезно анализировать собранные ими данные. Попробуйте задать свой вопрос ютубу в сочетании с каким-то из инструментов, в комментариях такое сложно будет объяснить.

Comment: jmeter - это уже когда понимаешь что. А чтобы понять как - это `F12` в Хроме. Очистить куки, открыть страницу логина. Открыть инструменты разработчика. Войти. Посмотреть запрос и ответ. Повторить его в коде.